# What does multiple $title = "string" mean?

Tags: cakephp

I am very new to CakePHP and I see multiple `$title="keycard"` written in the exact same way in multiple functions. What is the meaning of this? Are all the functions being "added" to keycard?

Edit: I have attached below the examples

```
function admin_keycard_index($aptNum){
$this->layout = 'admin_bootstrap';
$user = $this->Auth->user();
$title = "Keycards";
$currentTerm = $this->Timeframe->getCurrentTerm();
$this->Session->write('currentTerm',$currentTerm);
  $this->set('keycardState',$this->Keycard->getStates());
  $this->set('aptNum',$aptNum);
  $keycards = $this->Keycard->findAllByRoomNumber($aptNum);

function admin_reshall_index($buildingID = null) {
$this->layout = 'admin_bootstrap';
$user = $this->Auth->user();
$title = "Keycards";
$currentTerm = $this->Timeframe->getCurrentTerm();
$this->Session->write('currentTerm',$currentTerm);
$this->set('buildingID', $buildingID);
}
```

Comment: There is no “adding” explicitly going on with a [*simple assignment operator*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). As far as to “why” such was written as so (or even “what” it does overall) .. requires much more context. My from-experience initial retort is sloppy coding.

Comment: It's being set, but not actually used anywhere (e.g. in a `$this->set` call, which would set it for the template or layout to use), so I think you can remove it from such situations without any ill effect.

Comment: This means nothing if it is not passed on the view file and used it there.